# Login Required error using service account Google BigQuery API

Tags: python, google-api, google-bigquery, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I wrote a python script that called insert API of BigQuery to insert data to a table. I use service account for OAuth authentication. It functioned correctly for few days but now it gives Login Required error (401).  Following is the code:

```
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery']

credentials =ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/home/ubuntu/aha/udofy.json', scopes=scopes)

service = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

job_body = { } #Body JSON

request = service.jobs().insert(projectId=projectId, body=job_body)

response = request.execute()
```

I see the following error when I check the job logs on the UI:

```
{

"error": {

 "errors": [
   {

    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],

  "code": 401,

  "message": "Login Required"

 }

}
```

**API Response**:

```
{u'configuration': {u'query': {u'createDisposition': u'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                               u'destinationTable': {u'datasetId': u'co_gradeup_android_ANDROID',
                                                     u'projectId': u'udofy-1021',
                                                     u'tableId': u'user_answer_attempts'},
                               u'query': u' SELECT user_dim.user_id as user_id, event_dim.params.value.string_value as post_id, DATE(USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(event_dim.timestamp_micros)) as attempt_date, count(*) as attempt_count FROM [udofy-1021:co_gradeup_android_ANDROID.app_events_20161101] WHERE event_dim.name =\'Answer_Selected\' and event_dim.params.key = \'postId\' and user_dim.user_id is not null and user_dim.user_id != "" group by 1,2,3 ',
                               u'writeDisposition': u'WRITE_APPEND'}},
 u'etag': u'', #User_etag
 u'id': u'', #User_Id
 u'jobReference': {u'jobId': u'job_C9kSTaEOQBw0VPBEF_Yj44C0-Us',
                   u'projectId': u'udofy-1021'},
 u'kind': u'bigquery#job',
 u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/udofy-1021/jobs/job_C9kSTaEOQBw0VPBEF_Yj44C0-Us',
 u'statistics': {u'creationTime': u'1478082742163',
                 u'startTime': u'1478082742420'},
 u'status': {u'state': u'RUNNING'},
 u'user_email': u''} #service_account_email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the output schema/format of the query in the job body did not match the schema of the table in which the data was being inserted via the insert API. There was a minor change in the query which was executed in the job body.

The **output format** of the query should be **exact same** as the **table schema** in the the output data has to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The service account doesn't have permissions to access the big query project in question.   Service accounts are not you, it needs to be preauthorized.

No idea if you can grant another user access to a project but if you can take the service account email address and add it as a user.

This is all contingent on your service account code working.  My python skills are limited I will have to assume its right.

Comment: Service account email address is already added in the project users dashboard with Editor rights. Can it be a case of OAuth token expiration because it used to work fine till today?

Comment: Service accounts don't expire as long as they have access and the project wasn't deleted or regenerated on Google developer console.

Comment: Neither of them happened. I am running the code on a separate local server. Does that make a difference?

Comment: server shouldn't matter although what version of the library are you running?  Like I said I am not a python expert.  try doing a var dump of some kind of the service.

Comment: I am using version 1.5.5 of google-api-python-client. Should I share the output of vardump? It seems to be fine with all variables having the desired value.

Comment: Put the var dump in your question and wait for someone with more Python knowledge then me.  The problem is that you aren't logged in which means its not detecting your service account for some reason.  If it contains an access token just change it so no one can access your account.